# Como otimizar um select dentro de um update?

Tags: mysql, query, select, otimização, stored-procedures

Criei um *stored-procedure* que atualiza os saldos da tabela Movimentação. No começo tentei usar `From Movimentacao` dentro do `update` da movimentacao, só que retornou erro. Consertei esse problema fazendo um `FROM (SELECT * FROM Movimentacao) as L2`. Só que isso gerou outro problema: lentidão caso a tabela esteja grande demais, pois ele fica fazendo `SELECT * FROM Movimentacao` toda hora. Testei com 10000 registros e ficou muito lento. Estava quebrando a cabeça para construir uma *query* que fosse rápida no update com *select*, mas tá um pouco difícil.

Segue o código do stored-procedure em MySql:

---

```
BEGIN

 set @a:=0;

 update Movimentacao d set d.ordem = (select @a:=@a+1) where id_conta = wconta
 order by data;

 UPDATE Movimentacao set saldo= (SELECT SUM(IF(operacao = 'Entrada', valor, -valor))
 FROM (SELECT * FROM Movimentacao) as L2
 WHERE L2.ordem <= Movimentacao.ordem and id_conta = wconta order by data,ordem)
 WHERE id_conta = wconta
 ORDER BY data,ordem;

END
```

Comment: É necessário mesmo dois `Updates` com a mesma condição?

Comment: O primeiro update é para ordenar pela data para somar corretamente os saldos no segundo update. Foi assim que pensei em fazer na hora.

Comment: é realmente necessário o "SELECT * FROM Movimentacao" no from? se vc está atualizando a movimentação de uma conta, vc poderia limitar esse select para não precisar vir a tabela inteira, pelo que entendi, vc poderia fazer "SELECT * FROM Movimentacao where id_conta = m.id_conta" (considerando m um alias da tabela do update)

Comment: Por que Movimentacao tem saldo ? Em geral temos algo como estoque--<movimentacao onde estoque tem sim o saldo , se atualiza por trigger , procedure ou update isolado , pode-se ter uma procedure para atualizar saldos. Não entendi este saldo se retroalimentando. Para a Procedure de recomposição de saldos a otimização seria via cursores.

Answer (score 0):

Eu trabalho muito com otimização em consultas para o MS Sql Server. Em geral eu resolvo muita coisa com o uso de tabelas temporárias limitando o meu universo de dados.

Parece que você esta trabalhando com movimento financeiro e que vc precisa atualizar o saldo com a soma das operações anteriores aquele registro.

Parece que o MySQL aceita `CASE` e `INNER JOIN` em UPDATEs, por isso eu sugiro algo assim:

```
BEGIN

 set @a:=0;

 update Movimentacao d set d.ordem = (select @a:=@a+1) where id_conta = wconta order by data;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Temp_Movimentacao SELECT * FROM Movimentacao order by data;

  UPDATE Movimentacao AS M INNER JOIN 
      Temp_Movimentacao AS L2
      ON L2.ordem <= M.ordem AND id_conta = wconta
    SET M.saldo = 
        SUM(CASE L2.operacao = 'Entrada' THEN L2.valor ELSE L2.valor*-1 END)
    WHERE id_conta = wconta

END
```

Não entendi o uso de `ORDER` no `UPDATE` visto que não tem nenhum impacto lógico ao meu ver visto que você esta criando uma ordem baseado em datas, por isso eu tirei. Eu precisaria entender um pouco melhor seu problema.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo. Vou ver se testo hoje ainda.